# How to fix sound recording in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, recording

My Skype works correctly, people hear me well. But I cannot record sound from my microphone using standard Windows recording utility or Audacity. I have turned on the microphone in Sound Settings so I can hear myself from the speakers. But applications still record empty sound. How can I fix this?

I'm using Windows XP, with correct drivers installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> Control Panel -> Sound and Audio
>   Devices -> Voice (tab) -> Voice
>   Recording (group)

and select **Realtek HD Audio Input** (this can be different for different motherboards and sound cards)

You can try other options, however this option helped me. I also have Realtek HD Digital input, but I don't know what does it mean.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixing Windows XP Sound Recorder**

1. Go to Control Panel > Sound & Audio Devices > Look for Voice Recording.
2. Click Test Hardware - a wizard will help you setup.
3. Say hello and watch if you see the sound level go up and down. If it does then Sound recorder is working now.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to record Skype calls, [try this app](http://www.ifree-recorder.com/) its free to use to record your calls. I've used it for a few months it works well.

Comment: No, I just want to record sound.

Comment: @DIMEDROLL: what version of windows are you using, and have installed your correct drivers?